# Using g++ with libc++

Tags: g++, osx-mavericks, libstdc++, clang++, libc++

It's quite easy to get clang++ to use GCC's libstdc++ (`-stdlib=stdc++`), but how can I do the converse?  On OS X Mavericks, the c++ system library is libc++, which means that basically libstdc++ cannot be used (if you mix with other c++ libraries such as boost that have been compiled with libc++).  So, roughly, that means G++ is not usable...  Unless I can ask it to use libc++ rather than libstdc++.

Thanks.

## The script I use (EDIT)

I'm using the following script, `g++-libc++`, to run g++ on top of libc++, on Mac OS X with MacPorts (hence the `-mp` names.

```
#! /bin/sh

clangxx=clang++-mp-3.5
gxx=g++-mp-4.9

libcxx_includes=$($clangxx -print-search-dirs |
                  perl -ne 's{^libraries: =(.*)}{$1/../../../} && print')

exec $gxx -std=c++11 \
   -isystem ${libcxx_includes}/include/c++/v1 \
   -nostdinc++ -nodefaultlibs \
   -lc -lc++ -lc++abi -lgcc_s.10.5 \
   -Wl,-no_compact_unwind \
   "$@"
```

Comment: Just pass the right -I (or -isystem), -L and -l flags...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

`g++ -std=c++0x -nostdinc++ -nodefaultlibs -lc -isystem <path_to>/include/c++/v1 -lc++ -lc++abi -lgcc_s.10.5`

Comment: On linux, it's quite challenging to compile `libc++abi`. Replacing `-lc++abi` with `-lsupc++` worked for me, though.

Comment: I also had to add an include path for `bits/c++config.h`, but still failed: on Ubuntu 19.10 and stock GCC 9 (9.2.1) using `g++ -nostdinc++ -nodefaultlibs -lc -isystem /usr/include/c++/9 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9 -lc++ -lc++abi -lgcc_s main.cpp` I get `undefined reference to \`std::cout'`.

Comment: @user2023370: It looks like you are including `libstdc++` headers instead of `libc++` headers.